# QGis 3.4: GPKG vector layer with object form (relations with spatial and non-spatial datasets) to postgres database

Tags: qgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I have QGis project with a geopackage included. One layer in the geopackage contains a attribute form with relations to other layers (spatial and non-spatial). I have to convert it to a postgres database. Is there a way to transform the attribute form (as much as I know created with drag and drop) to a postgres db? And then to import the data?

I can create the database by transforming the geopackage to a postgres with GDAL ogr2ogr but how can I automatically include the relations in the attribute form?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think that is not possible.

The *Attributes Form* configurations are stored in the Style of the layer.

You can store the style in the same GeoPackage (e.g., saving as Default in the Datasource Database), and the style will be written in the *layer_styles* table.

But styles are XML documents, and a *Value Relation* widget, in QML format, looks like:

```xml
<field name="lines_fid">
 <editWidget type="ValueRelation">
  <config>
   <Option type="Map">
    <Option name="AllowMulti" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <Option name="AllowNull" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <Option name="FilterExpression" type="QString" value=""/>
    <Option name="Key" type="QString" value="fid"/>
    <Option name="Layer" type="QString" value="test_lines_0c79b239_4137_499a_b30b_bb81ee1f4fe7"/>
    <Option name="NofColumns" type="int" value="1"/>
    <Option name="OrderByValue" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <Option name="UseCompleter" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <Option name="Value" type="QString" value="values_field"/>
   </Option>
  </config>
 </editWidget>
</field>
```

I don't know an automatic way to transform that widget definition in an SQL column constraint to be included in the postgres database.